# What invokes the Oncreate() Method in Android Lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-developer-api

What invokes the Oncreate() Method in Android Lifecycle ?

I know what invokes the oncreate method in android lifecycle. but i don't know How OnCreate Method is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

The onCreate() method is where any initialization code should go, as this method always gets called after the activity has launched but before it starts running. An activity is running when it's visible in the foreground and the user can interact with it.
In Java, complier decided the starting point is from main() method, similarly in Android OS below are the check done, its OS feature where compiler takes a call:

1. Android OS first check for manifest file in application, first check
2. Look for the launcher activity
3. In launcher activity look for onCreate() method
4. Rest other life cycle method gets execute as per the situation